# Kadene Pact Contract "Required Capability Not Granted" error

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

I'm getting following error, while crediting an account `tuncatunc` in the reply file.

There are 2 keysets, `k-admin-keyset` and `k-player-keyset`.

`k-player-keyset` is used to create account

```
(create-account "tuncatunc" (read-keyset "k-player-keyset"))
```

`k-admin-keyset` is used to credit account.

```
(credit "tuncatunc" (read-keyset "k-admin-keyset") 111.12 )
```

The error message is

```
pact> (load "kazora.repl" true)
"Loading kazora.repl..."
"Setting transaction keys"
"Setting transaction data"
"Begin Tx 0"
"Loading fungible-v2.pact..."
"Loaded interface fungible-v2"
"Loading fungible-xchain-v1.pact..."
"Loaded interface fungible-xchain-v1"
"Namespace defined: free"
"Loading kazora.pact..."
"Namespace set to free"
"Keyset defined"
"Loaded module free.token-k, hash xissNdfI-0IWEgo_GDT-cGaTdeVL5Ea9lUMI6WSolO0"
"Commit Tx 0"
"Begin Tx 1"
"Using free.token-k"
"TableCreated"
true
"Write succeeded"
kazora.pact:264:4: require-capability: not granted: (free.token-k.CREDIT "tuncatunc")
 at kazora.pact:264:4: (require-capability (free.token-k.CREDIT "tuncatunc"))
 at kazora.repl:47:0: (credit "tuncatunc" KeySet {keys: [k-admin],pred: keys-all} 111.12)
```

The reply file

```
;; ========================================================
;;                1-load-environment-data
;; ========================================================

;; set transaction signature key to k-admin
(env-keys ["k-admin", "k-player"])
;; set environment data to the loans-admin-keyset with keys loansadmin and predicate function of keys-all
(env-data {
  "k-admin-keyset": {
    "keys": ["k-admin"],
    "pred": "keys-all"
  },
  "k-player-keyset": {
    "keys": ["k-player"],
    "pred": "keys-all"
  }
})


;; ========================================================
;;                 2-load-pact-file
;; ========================================================

;; begin a transaction
(begin-tx)
;; load loans.pact into the REPL
(load "fungible-v2.pact")
(load "fungible-xchain-v1.pact")
(define-namespace 'free (read-keyset "k-admin-keyset") (read-keyset "k-admin-keyset"))

(load "kazora.pact")
;; commit the transaction
(commit-tx)

;; ========================================================
;;                   3-call-functions
;; ========================================================


;; begin a transaction
(begin-tx)
(use free.token-k)
(create-table token-table)
(validate-account-id "tuncatunc")

(create-account "tuncatunc" (read-keyset "k-player-keyset"))
(credit "tuncatunc" (read-keyset "k-admin-keyset") 111.12 )
(get-balance "tuncatunc")
(commit-tx)
```

The pact contract

```
(namespace "free")
(define-keyset "free.k-admin-keyset" 
  (read-keyset "k-admin-keyset"))

(module token-k GOVERNANCE

  @doc "K token smart contract"

  @model
    [ (defproperty conserves-mass (amount:decimal)
        (= (column-delta token-table 'balance) 0.0))

      (defproperty valid-account-id (accountId:string)
        (and
          (>= (length accountId) 3)
          (<= (length accountId) 256)))
    ]

  (implements fungible-v2)
  (implements fungible-xchain-v1)

  ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; Schemas and Tables

  (defschema token-schema
    @doc " An account, holding a token balance. \
         \ \
         \ ROW KEY: accountId. "
    balance:decimal
    guard:guard
  )
  (deftable token-table:{token-schema})

  ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; Capabilities

  (defcap GOVERNANCE
    ()

    @doc " Give the admin full access to call and upgrade the module. "

    (enforce-keyset "free.k-admin-keyset")
  )

  (defcap ACCOUNT_GUARD
    ( accountId:string )
    @doc " Look up the guard for an account, required to debit from that account. "
    (enforce-guard (at 'guard (read token-table accountId ['guard])))
  )

  (defcap DEBIT
    ( sender:string )

    @doc " Capability to perform debiting operations. "

    (enforce-guard (at 'guard (read token-table sender ['guard])))
    (enforce (!= sender "") "Invalid sender.")
  )

  (defcap CREDIT
    ( receiver:string )

    @doc " Capability to perform crediting operations. "

    (enforce (!= receiver "") "Invalid receiver.")
  )

  (defcap TRANSFER:bool
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      amount:decimal )

    @doc " Capability to perform transfer between two accounts. "

    @managed amount TRANSFER-mgr

    (enforce (!= sender receiver) "Sender cannot be the receiver.")
    (enforce-unit amount)
    (enforce (> amount 0.0) "Transfer amount must be positive.")
    (compose-capability (DEBIT sender))
    (compose-capability (CREDIT receiver))
  )

  (defun TRANSFER-mgr:decimal
    ( managed:decimal
      requested:decimal )

    (let ((newbal (- managed requested)))
      (enforce (>= newbal 0.0)
        (format "TRANSFER exceeded for balance {}" [managed]))
      newbal
    )
  )

  (defcap TRANSFER_XCHAIN:bool
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      amount:decimal
      target-chain:string
    )

    @managed amount TRANSFER_XCHAIN-mgr
    (enforce-unit amount)
    (enforce (> amount 0.0) "Cross-chain transfers require a positive amount")
    (compose-capability (DEBIT sender))
  )

  (defun TRANSFER_XCHAIN-mgr:decimal
    ( managed:decimal
      requested:decimal
    )

    (enforce (>= managed requested)
      (format "TRANSFER_XCHAIN exceeded for balance {}" [managed]))
    0.0
  )

  (defcap TRANSFER_XCHAIN_RECD:bool
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      amount:decimal
      source-chain:string
    )
    @event true
  )

  ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; Constants

  (defconst INITIAL_SUPPLY:decimal 1000000000.0
    " Initial supply of 1 billion tokens. ")

  (defconst DECIMALS 12
    " Specifies the minimum denomination for token transactions. ")

  (defconst ACCOUNT_ID_CHARSET CHARSET_LATIN1
    " Allowed character set for account IDs. ")

  (defconst ACCOUNT_ID_PROHIBITED_CHARACTER "$")

  (defconst ACCOUNT_ID_MIN_LENGTH 3
    " Minimum character length for account IDs. ")

  (defconst ACCOUNT_ID_MAX_LENGTH 256
    " Maximum character length for account IDs. ")


  ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; Utilities

  (defun validate-account-id
    ( accountId:string )

    @doc " Enforce that an account ID meets charset and length requirements. "

    (enforce
      (is-charset ACCOUNT_ID_CHARSET accountId)
      (format
        "Account ID does not conform to the required charset: {}"
        [accountId]))

    (enforce
      (not (contains accountId ACCOUNT_ID_PROHIBITED_CHARACTER))
      (format "Account ID contained a prohibited character: {}" [accountId]))

    (let ((accountLength (length accountId)))

      (enforce
        (>= accountLength ACCOUNT_ID_MIN_LENGTH)
        (format
          "Account ID does not conform to the min length requirement: {}"
          [accountId]))

      (enforce
        (<= accountLength ACCOUNT_ID_MAX_LENGTH)
        (format
          "Account ID does not conform to the max length requirement: {}"
          [accountId]))
    )
  )

  ;; ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;; ; Fungible-v2 Implementation

  (defun transfer-create:string
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      receiver-guard:guard
      amount:decimal )

    @doc " Transfer to an account, creating it if it does not exist. "

    @model [ (property (conserves-mass amount))
             (property (> amount 0.0))
             (property (valid-account-id sender))
             (property (valid-account-id receiver))
             (property (!= sender receiver)) ]

    (with-capability (TRANSFER sender receiver amount)
      (debit sender amount)
      (credit receiver receiver-guard amount)
    )
  )

  (defun transfer:string
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      amount:decimal )

    @doc " Transfer to an account, failing if the account does not exist. "

    @model [ (property (conserves-mass amount))
             (property (> amount 0.0))
             (property (valid-account-id sender))
             (property (valid-account-id receiver))
             (property (!= sender receiver)) ]

    (with-read token-table receiver
      { "guard" := guard }
      (transfer-create sender receiver guard amount)
    )
  )

  (defun debit
    ( accountId:string
      amount:decimal )

    @doc " Decrease an account balance. Internal use only. "

    @model [ (property (> amount 0.0))
             (property (valid-account-id accountId))
           ]

    (validate-account-id accountId)
    (enforce (> amount 0.0) "Debit amount must be positive.")
    (enforce-unit amount)
    (require-capability (DEBIT accountId))

    (with-read token-table accountId
      { "balance" := balance }

      (enforce (<= amount balance) "Insufficient funds.")

      (update token-table accountId
        { "balance" : (- balance amount) }
      )
    )
  )

  (defun credit
    ( accountId:string
      guard:guard
      amount:decimal )

    @doc " Increase an account balance. Internal use only. "

    @model [ (property (> amount 0.0))
             (property (valid-account-id accountId))
           ]

    (validate-account-id accountId)
    (enforce (> amount 0.0) "Credit amount must be positive.")
    (enforce-unit amount)
    (require-capability (CREDIT accountId))

    (with-default-read token-table accountId
      { "balance" : -1.0
      , "guard"   : guard
      }
      { "balance" := balance
      , "guard"   := currentGuard
      }
      (enforce (= currentGuard guard) "Account guards do not match.")

      (let ((is-new
        (if (= balance -1.0)
            (enforce-reserved accountId guard)
          false)))

      (write token-table accountId
        { "balance" : (if is-new amount (+ balance amount))
        , "guard"   : currentGuard
        }
      ))
    )
  )

  (defun check-reserved:string (account:string)
    " Checks ACCOUNT for reserved name and returns type if \
    \ found or empty string. Reserved names start with a \
    \ single char and colon, e.g. 'c:foo', which would return 'c' as type."
    (let ((pfx (take 2 account)))
      (if (= ":" (take -1 pfx)) (take 1 pfx) "")))

  (defun enforce-reserved:bool (account:string guard:guard)
      @doc "Enforce reserved account name protocols."
      (if (validate-principal guard account)
        true
        (let ((r (check-reserved account)))
          (if (= r "")
            true
            (if (= r "k")
              (enforce false "Single-key account protocol violation")
              (enforce false
                (format "Reserved protocol guard violation: {}" [r]))
              )))))

  (defschema crosschain-schema
    @doc " Schema for yielded value in cross-chain transfers "
    receiver:string
    receiver-guard:guard
    amount:decimal
    source-chain:string
  )

  (defpact transfer-crosschain:string
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      receiver-guard:guard
      target-chain:string
      amount:decimal )

    @model [ (property (> amount 0.0))
             (property (!= receiver ""))
             (property (valid-account-id sender))
             (property (valid-account-id receiver))
           ]

    (step
      (with-capability (TRANSFER_XCHAIN sender receiver amount target-chain)

        (validate-account-id sender)
        (validate-account-id receiver)

        (enforce (!= "" target-chain) "empty target-chain")
        (enforce (!= (at 'chain-id (chain-data)) target-chain)
          "cannot run cross-chain transfers to the same chain")

        (enforce (> amount 0.0)
          "transfer quantity must be positive")

        (enforce-unit amount)

        ;; Step 1 - debit sender account on current chain
        (debit sender amount)

        (emit-event (TRANSFER sender "" amount))

        (let
          ((crosschain-details:object{crosschain-schema}
            { "receiver"       : receiver
            , "receiver-guard" : receiver-guard
            , "amount"         : amount
            , "source-chain"   : (at 'chain-id (chain-data))
            }
          ))
          (yield crosschain-details target-chain)
        )
      )
    )

    (step
      (resume
        { "receiver"       := receiver
        , "receiver-guard" := receiver-guard
        , "amount"         := amount
        }
        ;; Step 2 - credit receiver account on target chain
        (with-capability (CREDIT receiver)
          (credit receiver receiver-guard amount)
        )
      )
    )
  )

  (defun get-balance:decimal
    ( account:string )

    (at 'balance (read token-table account ['balance]))
  )

  (defun details:object{fungible-v2.account-details}
    ( account:string )

    (with-read token-table account
      { "balance" := balance
      , "guard"   := guard
      }
      { "account" : account
      , "balance" : balance
      , "guard"   : guard
      }
    )
  )

  (defun precision:integer
    ()

    DECIMALS
  )

  (defun enforce-unit:bool
    ( amount:decimal )

    @doc " Enforce the minimum denomination for token transactions. "

    (enforce
      (= (floor amount DECIMALS) amount)
      (format "Amount violates minimum denomination: {}" [amount])
    )
  )

  (defun create-account:string
    ( account:string
      guard:guard )

    @doc " Create a new account. "

    @model [ (property (valid-account-id account)) ]
    (enforce-reserved account guard)

    (insert token-table account
      { "balance" : 0.0
      , "guard"   : guard
      }
    )
  )

  (defun rotate:string
    ( account:string
      new-guard:guard )

    (with-read token-table account
      { "guard" := oldGuard }

      (enforce-guard oldGuard)
      (enforce-guard new-guard)

      (update token-table account
        { "guard" : new-guard }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to obtain the `CREDIT` capability in order to use the `credit` function.

Because the CREDIT capability cannot obtained directly, it uses `require-capability` instead of `with-capability` making it a private function, you need to obtain it indirectly: Its intended to be used by the `transfer` function.

By adding the `TRANSFER` capability on a transaction the CREDIT capability can be obtained, see compose-capability in the TRANSFER cap.